# Extract feature values from Solr

Tags: machine-learning, solr

I have 80000 Questions&Answers which indexed using Solr, and a feature file.
I'm trying to extract those feature **values** for each Q&A couple in order to use them for training by algorithm (such as LambdaMart).

The training Algorithm gets as input this format:

```
<label> qid:<qid> <feature>:<value> ... <feature>:<value> # <info>
```

For example:

```
3 qid:1 1:1 2:1 3:0 4:0.2 5:0 # 1A
2 qid:1 1:0 2:0 3:1 4:0.1 5:1 # 1B 
1 qid:1 1:0 2:1 3:0 4:0.4 5:0 # 1C
1 qid:1 1:0 2:0 3:1 4:0.3 5:0 # 1D  
1 qid:2 1:0 2:0 3:1 4:0.2 5:0 # 2A
```

Can anyone help me to extract those feature values?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, please edit your question and provide a code sample of what you tried to solve your problem. You should also tag the question with the proper language and libraries for processing the file. Thanks!

Comment: What is the Solr part of the question?

Comment: Hi, i have no code and the library i use is RankLib (can't tag it).  How can i extract the values of the features (like 'cosine similarity' ) for each Q&A using solr or a different program?. i need those values for the training algorithm.  please help me it's very important to me